# How can I establish the inverse function?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

How can I establish the inverse function?
$$f(x)=x^{4}-3x^{3}+4x^{2}-6x+4$$
redefining the function so that it is bijective I obtained:
$$\begin{array}{llll}f:&\left[\dfrac{3}{2},\infty\right)&\longrightarrow&\left[-\dfrac{17}{16},\infty\right)\\&x&\longmapsto&f(x)=x^{4}-3x^{3}+4x^{2}-6x+4\end{array}$$

How can I express the inverse function, or is it not possible?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

There is no inverse function to $f(x)=x^{4}-3x^{3}+4x^{2}-6x+4$. This is because $f(x)$ has two $x$ values for one $y$ value, which means $f^{-1}(x)$ will have two $y$ values for one $x$ value. Since this does not pass the vertical line test, the inverse of $f(x)=x^{4}-3x^{3}+4x^{2}-6x+4$ is **not a function.**

If you want to get the inverse function of $f(x)=x^{4}-3x^{3}+4x^{2}-6x+4$ on a specific domain to make the inverse a function, one way is to use the tedious **quartic formula**, which restates the inverse function as $f^{-1}(x)$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: You *can* technically define the inverse of a function if you restrict the domain. A famous example is $f(x) = \sin(x)$ with $x\in\left[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\right]$, with $\mathcal{Rng}(f) = [-1,1]$. The inverse function is $f^{-1}(x) = \arcsin(x)$, where the domain is $[-1,1]$ with range $\left[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\right]$